# The difference between Map() and map () from Purrr package in R

Tags: r

hi I was trying to add a name column into all of the elements in my list using the names of the list. That is I have 8 tables in my list, each table has its own name table 1...8. So later I can unlist them and differentiate where the table comes from.

I have read this post and the code works.
[R - Add columns to dataframes in list by looping through elements in a vector](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40251202/r-add-columns-to-dataframes-in-list-by-looping-through-elements-in-a-vector)

```
my_list <- Map(cbind, mylist, Cluster = names(mylist))
```

However, I don't quite understand the Map(). This is not the map() from Purrr package right? map() will take the arguments in order  map(data, function). I checked in Rstudio help on Map, it looks more confusing. And if I'm to use the Purrr map function, I tried this

```
my_list2 <- map(mylist, function(x)cbind(x,Cluster = names(x)))
```

it did not work. could someone enlighten me how Map works and if I'm going to use map(), what are the changes I should do?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

They are indeed different functions.  If your list is already named you can certainly use `purrr::map` to add a named column.  [Please see this recent question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64030238/r-create-new-dataframe-variable-based-on-list-element-name/64031195#64031195) since you didn't provide any specifics.

Best guess at what you want is:

```r
purrr::map2(mylist, names(mylist), ~ mutate(.x, new_column_name = .y))
```

Comment: Nice. Yes I have only heard of map so when I see the Map I was like whatttt. The code you gave is a great example. Can I also ask rookie questions about the ~ mutate(.x, new_column_name = .y).  What does the "~" do here? And for the .x and .y, they are just like spacehoolders for the mylist, and names() right?

Comment: The tilde ~ is simply a way to let `map` know that what follows is a "formula".  `.x` is the short hand for the first list we are passing (your list of dataframes) and .y refers to the second list we are passing which is the `names` of those dataframes.  `map` is for a single list, `map2` for two lists (your case) and `pmap` handles the case of three or more lists.  So for the first df in the list the formula for the answer is `mutate(data = mylist[[1]], new_column_name = names(mylist[[1]]))`

Comment: Thank you for your patience, appreciate. btw, should I then add the tilde to all functions passing through map()?

Comment: It's my preference but there are other possibilities.  Straight from the doco for example... "map2(x, y, ~ .x + .y)
# Or just
map2(x, y, `+`)"

Comment: Thank you :) Sorry for all the noob questions

Answer (score 4):

Maybe this is what you are looking for. To add a column with the name of the list you have to loop both over the list and the names. This could be easily achieved via `purrr::imap` which is a wrapper for `purrr::map2` or you can use base `Map`. The main difference is probably that in `Map` the function to apply is the first argument. Additonally the `purrr` family of `map` functions allows for using formula notation (see the example in my code) for writing anonymous functions

```r
mylist <- list(
  a = data.frame(x = 1 , y = 2),
  b = data.frame(x = 3, y = 4)
)

purrr::imap(mylist, ~ cbind(.x, Cluster = .y))
#> $a
#>   x y Cluster
#> 1 1 2       a
#> 
#> $b
#>   x y Cluster
#> 1 3 4       b

Map(function(x, y) { cbind(x, Cluster = y) }, mylist, names(mylist))
#> $a
#>   x y Cluster
#> 1 1 2       a
#> 
#> $b
#>   x y Cluster
#> 1 3 4       b
```

Comment: brilliant. Thank you for helping me understand the Map and map